# Function from normal groups, to normal groups of cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I do not understand this proof in my book, so after struggling a lot with it I tried writing my own proof. Can you please verify that my proof is correct?

[image]
**My proof:**

**one to one:**

Assume that $\phi(L_1)=\phi(L_2)=\gamma[L_1]=\gamma[L_2]$(these are normal subgroups, I will not prove this), but for contradiction that $L_1 \ne L_2$, then without loss of generality there is an element $x \in L_1, x \not\in L_2$. Since $x \in L_1$, we have that $\gamma(x)=(xN)$, but there must be an $x_2 \in L_2$ where $(xN)=(x_2 N)$, because the image of $L_1, and\  L_2$ are the same.But then we have that $x=x_2n$, where $n \in N$. But since $L_2$ is a group which contains N, we see that $x_2n=x$ must be contained in $L_2$ hence we have a contradiciton, and the function is one to one.

**onto:**

Let H be a normal subgroup of $G/N$, then $\gamma^{-1}[H]$ is a normal subgroup of G(I will not prove this).

If I can prove that $N \subseteq \gamma^{-1}[H]$, and that $\phi(\gamma^{-1}[H])=\gamma[\gamma^{-1}[H]]=H$, I will be done.

First if $x \in N$, then $\gamma(x)=(N)$(Here (N) is a coset). This is the identity coset, so it is contained in H. But then x is in $\gamma^{-1}[H]$.

From elementary set theory we allways have that $\gamma[\gamma^{-1}[H]] \subseteq H$. So we have to prove the opposite containment. Let $y \in H$, hence y is a coset and $y=(gN), g \in G$. This means that $g \in \gamma^{-1}[H]$, since $\gamma(g)=(gN)=y$ is in $H$. But then we get that $\gamma(g)$ must be in $\gamma[\gamma^{-1}[H]]$, because $g \in \gamma^{-1}[H]$. Hence $y=\gamma (g) \in \gamma[\gamma^{-1}[H]]$, and we are done.

Is this correct? Have I missed something, or have the proof in my book something essential I don't have?

Also in the last paragraph of the books proof, the say "Then $\phi(\gamma^{-1}[H])=\gamma[\gamma^{-1}[H]]=H$." But have they even proved this? Can they just say it without an argument like what I did?

Comment: What book is that? Not only the proof seems to be cumbersome (using results with worrying numbering...) but the lemma is a just a fraction of the very important Correspondence Theorem, which says lots more than what this lemma says.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, which may or may not be useful to you. Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the set of normal subgroups of $G$ containing $N$, and let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the set of normal subgroups of $\gamma(G) = G/N$

Define $\psi: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ by $\psi(H) = \gamma^{-1}(H)$. We need to be sure that this definition makes *sense*, that is, for every $H \in \mathcal{D}$ that $\psi(H) \in \mathcal{C}$. It's clear that $\psi$ is well-defined on SUBSETS of $G/N$, but it's not immediately obvious $\psi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N$.

Now if $n \in N$, then $\gamma(n) = e_{G/N} = N$, since $N = \text{ker }\gamma$. Since $N$ is the identity element of $G/N$, we have $N \in H$, whence $ n \in \gamma^{-1}(H)$. So, at the very least, $\psi(H)$ contains $N$ as a subset.

Suppose $x,y \in \psi(H)$. This means $\gamma(x),\gamma(y) \in H$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, we have $\gamma(x)\gamma(y)^{-1} \in H$, thus $\gamma(xy^{-1}) \in H$ (since $\gamma$ is a homomorphism), so that $xy^{-1} \in \gamma^{-1}(H)$, and $\psi(H)$ is thus a subgroup of $G$.

It is easy to see $\psi(H)$ is normal in $G$, for take any $x \in \psi(H)$ and any $g \in G$. Then $\gamma(gxg^{-1}) = \gamma(g)\gamma(x)\gamma(g)^{-1}$, and $\gamma(x) \in H$, which is normal in $G/N$, thus $\gamma(g)\gamma(x)\gamma(g)^{-1} \in H$. Since this equals $\gamma(gxg^{-1})$, we see $gxg^{-1} \in \gamma^{-1}(H)$, so $\psi(H)$ is normal in $G$.

It's important to recognize that given $L \in \mathcal{C}$, that $\phi(L)$ is just $L/N$. Furthermore, if $g \not\in L$, we cannot have $\gamma(g) \in L/N$, because this implies $g = xn$ for some $x \in L, n \in N$, whence $x^{-1}g \in N \subset L$, and thus $g \in Lx = L$. So the pre-image of $L/N$ under $\gamma$ is *precisely* $L$.

That's the "ugly part", it's downhill from here:

$\phi(\psi(H)) = \gamma(\gamma^{-1}(H)) = H$, for any $H \in \mathcal{D}$, and for any $L \in \mathcal{C}$:

$\psi(\phi(L)) = \gamma^{-1}(\gamma(L)) = \gamma^{-1}(L/N) = L$, so that we see $\psi$ is a two-sided functional inverse to $\phi$ which is therefore bijective.

---

I tried (to the best of my meager abilities) to shy away from invoking cosets, to keep the "layers" straight (we have group elements, cosets, subgroups, and sets of subgroups) and what is going on is just a correspondence between sets of subgroups. You can think of $\gamma$ as doing this: shrinking $N$ down to a point, but preserving the group structure "above $N$" faithfully. I find the notion of cosets a bit cumbersome myself, and prefer to think of quotient groups as "homomorphic images" (the homomorphism does some "collapsing" by pretending all elements of $N$ are the identity).